# How to keep the Shell configurable with PRISM 4.1 & Unity?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm, unity-container, prism-4

I am writing a WPF application using PRISM 4.1 & Unity. The application will have every UI component configurable, including the Shell itself!

E.g. I have an interface called `IShell`. Consumers of the app can have their own implementation of `IShell` if they are not satisfied with my default implementation which has Regions and Views defined in some fixed way.

Now from my Bootstrapper class (which inherits `UnityBootstrapper`), I want to know the type registered for `IShell` with the Unity container. The overriden `CreateShell` will return configured type of the `IShell`.

My `App.config` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>
  <unity>
    <container>
        <register type="Interfaces.IShell, Interfaces" mapTo="PrismApp.Shell, PrismApp"/>
    </container>
  </unity>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

In Bootstrapper class, I have following code:

```
public class PrismAppBootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        var obj =  ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IShell>() as DependencyObject;
        return obj;
    }
}
```

In the WPF application's App.xaml.cs, I am instantiating `PrismAppBootstrapper`:

```
 PrismAppBootstrapper prismAppBootstrapper = new PrismAppBootstrapper();
        prismAppBootstrapper.Run();
```

However, when I run this code, I get the Exception : "*InvalidOperationException - The current type, Interfaces.IShell, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?*"

**How to solve this problem?
Why does application fail to know the registered type of IShell which is there in app.config file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping the Shell configurable is possible with the Unity container.

The problem was that my Unity Container was not properly configured to read mapping/registrations from the app.config file. So it failed to know the mapping of `IShell` at run time.

I had to override other methods along with `CreateShell` in my `PrismAppBootstrapper` class.

E.g.

```
public class PrismAppBootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
    {
        protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
        {
            ModuleCatalog catalog = new ConfigurationModuleCatalog();
            return catalog;
        }

        protected override void ConfigureContainer()
        {
            base.ConfigureContainer();
            UnityConfigurationSection configurationSection =
                (UnityConfigurationSection) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
            if (configurationSection != null)
            {
                configurationSection.Configure(this.Container);
            }
        }

        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            IShell shell = this.Container.TryResolve<IShell>();
            return shell as Window;
        }

        protected override void InitializeShell()
        {
            base.InitializeShell();

            Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Shouldnt you instead use the UnityBootstrapper's Container to resolve your shell?

```
var obj =  Container.Resolve<IShell>() as DependencyObject;
return obj;
```

Comment: I have already tried this. This overload of `Resolve` is not available anymore :(

Comment: You need to reference UnityExtensions:
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions;